# How to insert a string which contains an “;”

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL Developer 4.2.0.17.089
I need to perform an update using a string which contains ";". 
Specifically:

```
update <table_name> set <field_name>='....
 <style>
    .SectionHeading {
                    font-size: 12pt;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-family:Calibri;
                    color:#548DD4;
    }
    </style>
....'
where <condition>;
```

No matter what I do I get 
SQL Error: ORA-01756: quoted string not properly terminated 
after the first semicolon

It perfectly works with SQL Developer 4.1.3.20.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in SQL Developer 4.2 (though I can't find anything related in MoS or the SD foum); it works OK in 17.2 too. And as `sqlterminator` is obsolete and ignored, the only way I can see to work around it in 4.2 is to enclose your statement in a dummy anonymous PL/SQL block - it isn't confused by the semicolons when it knows its in a PL/SQL context:

```
begin
-- start real code
update <table_name> set <field_name>='....
 <style>
    .SectionHeading {
                    font-size: 12pt;
                    font-weight: bold;
                    font-family:Calibri;
                    color:#548DD4;
    }
    </style>
....'
where <condition>;
-- end real code
end;
/
```

Which isn't ideal. A better solution may be to [upgrade to the current version](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), if you are able to.